# how can I load wasm function in a react app

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webassembly

I have some JS code which I am compiling to a Wasm using Javy. I have this working fine and I can run and test the code from the terminal using wasmtime.

I want to run this code from a react app. I'm able to load the module but I can't call any functions on it.

Here is a simplified version of my JS code, in reality main is importing a whole bunch of classes and doing a load of stuff:

```
export function main(){
    console.log("HELLO")
}
```

And I have a wit file:

```
package local:main;

world index-world {
  export main: func(); 
}
```

So I export that using javy:

```
javy compile main.js --wit main.wit -n index-world -o main.wasm
```

and I can invoke it using wasmtime:

```
wasmtime run --invoke main main.wasm
```

That all works.

But when loading in react as described [here](https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/react-webassembly-bringing-high-performance-your-web-app-alex-lomia/):

```
useEffect(() => {

    const loadWasm = async () => {
      const wasmModule = await import('./main.wasm');
      
      console.log(wasmModule.main())
    };

    loadWasm();
  }, [])
```

I get `wasmModule.main is not a function`

What is going on here?

How can I load .wasm file into react and use it in my app?

I do also need to be able to pass in arguments and get the returned result to my function. And it seems from reading the [Javy repo](https://github.com/bytecodealliance/javy) that might not be possible.

Comment: I'm confused - why are you turning JS into WASM? It's already JS, the browser can run that just fine?

Comment: I have an engine that is doing quite a bit of logic, compiling to wasm serves two purposes. Performance benefits and some protection over sensitive code, as this is for a SaaS web app. Executing the JS on the backend was another option but I'm exploring wasm as a way of saving cost. I am also considering rewriting the engine in python at some stage for various reasons.